# Highcharts: Graph with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, charts, highcharts

As you could pass the following values to a Highcharts graph :

```
{"titulos": [{"title": "Proveedor"}, {"title": "Total"}], "data": [["Dolex - 9028382372873", 88.59], ["BIOCLEAN - 2093029302930", 2.8]]}
```

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let's try: http://jsfiddle.net/w02p4cru/

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    "titulos": [{
      "title": "Proveedor"
    }, {
      "title": "Total"
    }],
    "data": [
      ["Dolex - 9028382372873", 88.59],
      ["BIOCLEAN - 2093029302930", 2.8]
    ]
  });
```

Turns out that you can, but I guess that is not the desired chart that you will get, since really there won't be anything. Chart's option doesn't match required options format explained in [Docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart) nor [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

If you change your options to match requirements, then your chart will look like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w02p4cru/1/

Code:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    "title": {
      "text": "Proveedor"
    },
    "subtitle": {
      "text": "Total"
    },
    "series": [{
      "data": [
        ["Dolex - 9028382372873", 88.59],
        ["BIOCLEAN - 2093029302930", 2.8]
      ]
    }]
  });
```

This might not be the chart you are looking for because you have not explained what exactly do you need, but general idea is to use required options format.

Comment: Thanks friend, I have the idea to do so.